# How to make import and export (or equivalent) work with unique notebook contexts

Tags: export, import, contexts

I currently have my notebook's default context set to "Unique to this notebook", which is useful for when I'm doing multiple projects.

However, whenever I try to use e.g `DumpSave["data.mx",data]`, upon using `DumpGet["data.mx"]` in a new notebook, I do not have anything defined on the symbol `data`; I suspect this is because upon using `DumpGet["data.mx"]`, it loads the definition including the original notebook's context.

If I set both the original and new notebook to Global, everything works as expected. Is there a way to resolve this without resorting to using Global as the default context?

For more detailed code, here is the results upon using `DumpSave` and `DumpGet` in a single notebook, with the context set to "Unique to this notebook":

```
data={1,2,3,4};
DumpSave["data.mx",data];
Clear[data]
DumpGet["data.mx"]
data
```

> `{1,2,3,4}`

In a new notebook,

```
DumpGet["data.mx"]
data
```

> `data`
> with `data` still being in blue.

Comment: Works fine with `Save` and `Get`. `DumpGet` is undocumented, but `DumpSave` and `Get` does not work either (works fine in the `Global` context). Might be a bug.